# RuntimeError: Failed to add edge detection - On Raspberrypi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio, edge-detection

I'm working on a button example on a Raspberry Pi. I found [this](https://raspberrypihq.com/use-a-push-button-with-raspberry-pi-gpio/) tutorial on the internet, and I was trying to complete it 1 by 1. The code is exactly the same, and I'm sure I used the correct pins.

This is what the code looks like:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO # Import Raspberry Pi GPIO library

def button_callback(channel):
    print("Button was pushed!")

GPIO.setwarnings(False) # Ignore warning for now
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Use physical pin numbering
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN) # Set pin 10 to be an input pin and set initial value to be pulled low (off)

GPIO.add_event_detect(10,GPIO.RISING,callback=button_callback) # Setup event on pin 10 rising edge

message = input("Press enter to quit\n\n") # Run until someone presses enter

GPIO.cleanup() # Clean up
```

And this is how the Breadboard is wired:
[image: Wiring schema]

Somehow, if I try to run the python file, I get the following error:
[image: error]

I've done some research and found out that the python file probably isn't the problem. It's more likely that it's the user privileges. For other people, it worked to just run the file as sudo, but that didn't work for me.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Does the behavior change if you use pin 11 instead of pin 10?

Comment: No it doesnt. Its the same for all pins

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have the same problem today.  Pin 10, 16 and 18 sudo and not sudo.

Comment: While GPIO seems to work fine when running as non-root user (provided your user has priviledges (via group) to access /dev/gpiomem), interrupts don't seem to work.
In addition, as root user I was only able to add interrupts to certain pins (e.g. pin GPIO24)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I moved a script from an old RPi to a new one. I solved the problem by installing the new gpio lib:

```bash
sudo apt remove python3-rpi.gpio

sudo apt install python3-rpi-lgpio
```

More information [here](https://pypi.org/project/rpi-lgpio/).